# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am building a dotnet 6 application on Visual Studio 2022 and am facing some issues while using the add-migration command. Here is my code and the output for add-migration command. I have tried using the latest Nuget packages, using the current project as the starting project and so on but no luck.

```
namespace Mango.Services.Identity.DbContexts
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

**Here is my Program.cs:**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);



var app = builder.Build();
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();


var build = builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
}).AddInMemoryIdentityResources(SD.IdentityResources)
           .AddInMemoryApiScopes(SD.ApiScopes)
           .AddInMemoryClients(SD.Clients)
           .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

build.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

**Output from add-migration command**

```
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Mango.Services.Identity.DbContexts.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Mango.Services.Identity.DbContexts.ApplicationDbContext'.
```